# Math round function with variable number of digits

Tags: c++

How can I use the math round function same as excel round function

```
float round( float arg );
```

round( number, **num_digits** )

- If num_digits is greater than 0, then number is rounded to the specified number of decimal places.
- If num_digits is 0, the number is rounded to the nearest integer.
- If num_digits is less than 0, the number is rounded to the left of the decimal point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Round a float to a given precision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208971/round-a-float-to-a-given-precision)

Comment: I don't think this is actually a duplicate of that, only because he wants to be able to round to the left of the decimal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple arithmetic,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>

float my_round( float arg, int digits )
{
    float retValue = arg * pow(10.0f,(float)digits);
    retValue = round(retValue);
    return retValue * std::pow(10.0f,(float)-digits);
}


int main()
{
    float value = 12.3456789f;
    for(int i=-1;i<6;i++)
    {
            printf("%f\n", my_round(value, i));
    }
}
```

should do the trick, (compiled with g++)

output is :

```
10.000000
12.000000
12.300000
12.349999
12.346001
12.345699
12.345679
```