# C++ Rounding random double

Tags: c++, random

I'm having some issues with sorting out a random double to be only one decimal point. I've given it a look online and, from what I can tell and understand, I've got everything correct. Obviously not, however. Specifically, it appears that I may be using 'round()' incorrectly because, even when I don't do all the other multiplication (etc) to it, it doesn't round the double.

```
double u;
srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    u = (double)rand()/(RAND_MAX+1) + (rand()%101); //Acquire random number, turn it into decimal and then add it to another number between 0-100.
    u *= 10; //Shift numbers left to remove first decimal from round.
    round(u); //Round to nearest whole number.
    u /= 10; //Shift right to return the first decimal.

    cout<<u<<" "<<flush;
}
```

This method seems terrible to me. Obviously it won't work up at the higher reaches of double (since *10 might overload it, or whatever it's called). I would like someone to: 
A. Show me where I went wrong with this code or, alternatively, hint it. 
B. Suggest a better, more efficient way of doing this. As I'm sure there definitely is one.
C. Show me to round to decimal points other than the 1st.

And much appreciated in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208971/round-a-float-to-a-given-precision

Comment: What range of random numbers do you want?

Comment: Your code doesn't round because you're not doing anything with the rounded value - `round` doesn't modify its parameter, it returns the result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding Number to 2 Decimal Places in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343890/rounding-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why `std::rand()` keeps being recommended, when its apparent simplicity is [misleading](http://www.eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx) and we have had [much better tools](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) for half a decade now.

C++11 random generators are easier to use *correctly* and you'll get statistically better results. You also have the choice of different engines and distributions, in case you need them.

```
// Setup
std::default_random_engine generator;
generator.seed(/* truly random seed, e.g. from std::random_device */);
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(/* your range */);

// Usage
double randomNumber = distribution(generator);
double rounded = std::round(10. * randomNumber) / 10.;
```

Comment: `double rounded = std::round(10. * rounded) / 10.;`? Typo?

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes, indeed, thanks. Was that the reason for the downvote?

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. Looks good to me, and we all knew what you *meant*.

Comment: Thanks for this. Just had a look at those links so I'll try to convert any reference of rand() in the tutorials I'm doing to use this method instead. Where is this 'default_random_engine' coming from, however? Is it in automatically available in any c++ program with iostream or is it in a .h file? My test code picked it up immediately.

Comment: @System It's in the header `<random>`, as you can see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) for example. The fact that some standard libraries include more headers than necessary doesn't matter; you should not rely on such behavior because it's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to

1. Generate random integer
2. Cast it to double
3. Divide by 10

   ```
   double d = rand();
   d /= 10;

   // now d will be xxxxx.y
   ```

Comment: No idea why I didn't think of this.