# comparison float rounding fails System.Math.RoundTo C++ XE7

Tags: c++, precision, c++builder-xe7

I've been trying to round a float value to 4 precision without success.

```
float fconv = 1.0f;
float fdata = 39.934543423412f;
float fres = RoundTo(fdata*fconv, -4);

if(fres <= 39.9345f){do something;} //<-- unwanted behavior
```

Wanted result is 39.934500000000
Actual result is 39.934543423412

I've tried many methods including [Round a float to a given precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208971/round-a-float-to-a-given-precision) without success.

I'm working on an AMD FX83xx 64bit. Program is built in 32bit Debug using XE7

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired precision of 6 decimal digits is very near the precision limits for a float data type.  The epsilon, or delta between consecutive representable floating point values, for a number around 40f is about 7.63E-6, so there's only a couple of bits different between the 'best' value and what you're getting.  This is possibly due to rounding that close to the limit, but I'm not sure.