# How to print out the number 78.125 with two digits after the decimal point as 78.13 in C++

Tags: c++

My assignment involve printing out double numbers with 2 digits after the decimal point. In one of the example tests, I got the output is 78.125. My teacher taught me to use the setprecision function to print out the number

```
#include <iomanip> 
...some code
cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
cout << x /*the number*/
```

Normally this would do just fine. However the example output is 78.13 while the output of my code is 78.12. I can't figure out anyway to do this.

Comment: Hmm, prints 78.13 with visual studio, but prints 78.12 [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e9ab9c875d15655).

Comment: AFAIK the round up/down behavior is implementation defined.  If that is the case you will have to manually round it yourself like they do [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343890/rounding-number-to-2-decimal-places-in-c)

Comment: I would imagine [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208971/round-a-float-to-a-given-precision) to be a better duplicate...

Comment: Note that 78.125 can be represented *exactly* in IEEE754 floating point.

Comment: Yes, it can be represented exactly. But if the compiler uses a general algorithm to do the conversion, it may use the imprecise binary forms of 0.1, 0.01 and 0.001 to multiply 1, 2 and 5 and add things up to get some error. Is that possible?

Comment: You could also do out = round(x * 100) / 100; before outputting the number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rounding behaviour of `std::cout` and `std::setprecision` is *implementation defined*.

C++11 clears up this mess by supplying a function called `std::fesetround` which you can call using

`std::fesetround(FE_TONEAREST);`

before your `std::cout` statement. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/feround for more details.

Comment: Example, please? I can't get this to work [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1384edecedc21010).