# What is the practical use of changing the rounding mode in floating point evnironment?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, ieee-754

I'm trying to find a good use for changing rounding mode in IEEE-754 floating-point environment.

I'm looking mostly from perspective of C and C++ code. There, it can be done using

```
int fesetround(int round)
```

function from `"fenv.x"` (or `<cfenv>` in C++).

The best use I could find is setting the environment to `FE_TONEAREST`, if for any godforsaken reason it wasn't the default.

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39878369/how-to-print-out-the-number-78-125-with-two-digits-after-the-decimal-point-as-78/39878561#39878561) someone suggested using it to get some implementation-dependent behavior of string formatting. I personally find this answer completely wrong, and I believe changing rounding modes around formatting functions can only result in unexpected, or simply wrong behavior.

Another thing that is changed by rounding mode, are the functions: `nearbyint` and `rint`. But why would you ever want to use them, instead of dispatching to `floor`, `ceil` and `trunc` functions?

That leaves us with the only useful part being local difference in floating point arithmetic. Where could that be useful? I was trying to find some niche use for that, but so far I couldn't find any.

Comment: Have you looked at the niche "interval arithmetic"? Obviously, instructions with baked in rounding modes (like on GPUs, accessible via intrinsics) are more useful for that, but in a pinch a dynamically changeable rounding mode will do, at a cost in performance.

Comment: Background reading - https://www.exploringbinary.com/inconsistent-rounding-of-printed-floating-point-numbers/ and possibly https://www.exploringbinary.com/tag/floating-point/

Answer (score 0):

The rouding modes have little to do with the floor and ceiling (the latter round *to integers*). I don't know about a `trunk` function.

Changing the rounding rule might be useful in some sophisticated cases where theoretical study shows that a particular rule has advantages over other or gives some desirable guarantee.

Comment: [`trunc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/trunc), not `trunk()`. It truncates towards zero.