# What is the correct way to raise an integer to a positive integer power in C++?

Tags: c++, math, numerical

We know that for [various reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398442/why-isnt-int-powint-base-int-exponent-in-the-standard-c-libraries), there is no standard integer power function in C++. I'm performing exact arithmetic with rather small integers, what is the correct way to compute powers?

Comment: What is wrong with [std::pow](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow)?

Comment: How about `pow(x, y) = exp(y * log(x))`? However you get three floating point errors here with weird numbers. Or could you explain what you're up to?

Comment: `std::pow` uses floating point numbers, leading to potential innacuracies. I want the exact value.

Comment: What's wrong with repeated multiplication since you're only interested in small integer powers ?

Comment: Repeated multiplication with a tail-recursive function could be what you want.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark : if that's indeed the best / fastest solution, nothing.

Comment: You might want to look at the individual bits of the exponent...

Comment: This is a non-dupe in the sense that the question over there was specifically labelled "homework", and it got home-worky answers. This question has a highly-upvoted answer with an iterative solution by-squaring. Whatever we think about the likelihood of a C++ compiler making a tail-call optimization, it's how a *lot* of real programmers would write it in practice. That other question didn't draw any such answer at all.

Comment: Have to agree with Steve here that this isn't an "exact dupe", so I've re-opened.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The standard, fast exponentiation uses repeated squaring:

```
uint_t power(uint_t base, uint_t exponent)
{
    uint_t result = 1;

    for (uint_t term = base; exponent != 0; term = term * term)
    {
        if (exponent % 2 != 0) { result *= term; }
        exponent /= 2;
    }

    return result;
}
```

The number of steps is logarithmic in the value of `exponent`. This algorithm can trivially be extended to modular exponentiation.

---

**Update:** Here is a modified version of the algorithm that performs one less multiplication and handles a few trivial cases more efficiently. Moreover, if you know that the exponent is never zero and the base never zero or one, you could even remove the initial checks:

```
uint_t power_modified(uint_t base, uint_t exponent)
{
    if (exponent == 0) { return 1;    }
    if (base < 2)      { return base; }

    uint_t result = 1;

    for (uint_t term = base; ; term = term * term)
    { 
        if (exponent % 2 != 0) { result *= term; }
        exponent /= 2;
        if (exponent == 0)     { break; }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: @PeterWood: It's commonly known, it's general (the same works for multiplication-in-terms-of-addition), it's fast (logarithmic), it's simple, and it exploits some nice machine properties (integer division by two is very fast)... so I'd say it's hard to come up with something better.

Comment: The most voted answer (though, unfortunately, not the accepted one) to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505675/power-of-an-integer-in-c proposes a variation on this algorithm, which we can consider more *standard* because it appears in Knuth. But the idea is the same.

Comment: @Gorpik: That answer doesn't look tail-recursive to me. I wouldn't feel comfortable suggesting that for anything but an educational or theoretical work.

Comment: Indeed, it is not tail-recursive, just recursive. And I agree that your solution would work better; in fact, I have upvoted it.

Answer (score 19):

You can use `std::pow(double a, double b)`. There will be no inaccuracies if both `a`, `b` and the result fit into a 32-bit integer!

The reason is that the 64-bit double precision fully covers the range of 32-bit integers.

Comment: You still have to round properly here, since the double result might be something like 15.9999999 which could be truncated if carelessly converted back to an int.

Comment: @NovaDenizen No, the doubles cover the 32-bit integers exactly. In other words, there is a double with exactly zero fractional part for every integer. And pow(), like other arithmetic operations, must give "the closest possible" double answer, which in this case will equal to an integer.

Comment: Not completely accurate for all 64-bit integers, but interesting answer nevertheless.

Comment: @static_rtti: It's true for all integers that fit entirely into the mantissa, which is 24 bits for a `float`, 53 bits for a `double` and 64 bits for a `long double` in IEEE754.

Comment: @KerrekSB: so which one should be used, in which circumstances ? The two answers are very different methods...

Comment: @static_rtti: Measure and compare! I think the pure-integer one should be better, but I haven't actually measured it. That said, the pure-integer one can use 64-bit integers all the way...

Comment: @user1698678 The C standard requires that all calculations be accurate to within 1 ULP (unit of least precision), which means the true answer can be +/- 1 ULP, so my caution still stands.  If C used a 1/2 ULP accuracy standard then you would be correct.

Comment: @static_rtti: Quick test, 10M times 7^11: Integer (fast 32 bit): 0.5s. Double: 9.0s.

Comment: @KerrekSB : thanks for testing! Your test was on x86-64, I suppose?

Comment: If you're worried about rounding, why not overload pow for ints and wrap the return of the double version in an std::lround? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round

Answer (score 4):

While Kerrek's answer is correct, there is also a "secret" feature in g++ to do this efficiently.  If you look at the SGI power function, it can be easily adapted to do what you want:

http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/power.html

In g++, this is implemented as [__gnu_cxx::power](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/libstdc++/api/a01595.html#ga52a0d4d0aad4e35cbcc82c8be1dfcebe).  You probably shouldn't use these things in production code though...

Comment: Woohoo, awesome, thanks a lot for sharing! I couldn't care less about Windows compatibility for my code :-D

Comment: Good to know - I'll add this to my test and compare. People have been asking for a `power` function in the standard library for some time; I think they have that SGI function in mind.

Comment: Testing this on x86_64 with a `uint_fast64_t`, `__gnu_cxx::power` is slightly slower than my algorithm (3.5s vs 2.9s on 1bn computations of 12^15).

Comment: @KerrekSB well duh the sgi version uses templates

Comment: @pyCthon: templates are evaluated at compile-time, they have no impact whatsoever on runtime performance.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers here, there is also a nice article on Wikipedia explaining various different implementations here -> [LINK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)