# c++ power of integer, template meta programming

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

I want to make a function which returns a power of integer.
Please read the fmuecke's solution in 
[power of an integer in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505675/power-of-an-integer-in-c) .

However, I want to generalize his solution to the arbitrary type T.
Since c++11 has constexpr, I guess this is possible.

Naively, I tried something like,

```
template<class T, int N>
inline constexpr T pow(const T x){
    return pow<N-1>(x) * x;
}
template<class T>
inline constexpr T pow<T, 1>(const T x){
    return x;
}
template<class T>
inline constexpr T pow<T, 0>(const T x){
    return 1;
}
```

Actually this approach failed since the partial specialization for function template is not allowed.

And one more question. I heard that it is up to the compiler whether the constexpr function is evaluated in compile time or not.
How do I force it to compute for general type.
I read from somewhere that one of the simplest hack for integral consts is to wrap it in std::integral_const::value.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Solution using recursion:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
inline constexpr T pow(const T base, unsigned const exponent)
{
    // (parentheses not required in next line)
    return (exponent == 0) ? 1 : (base * pow(base, exponent-1));
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "pow(2, 4): " << pow(2, 4) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "pow(5, 0): " << pow(5, 0) << std::endl;
}
```

[Jeremy W. Murphy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/413597/jeremy-w-murphy) suggested/requested a version using exponentiation by squaring:

```
template<class T>
inline constexpr T pow(const T base, unsigned const exponent)
{
    // (parentheses not required in next line)
    return (exponent == 0)     ? 1 :
           (exponent % 2 == 0) ? pow(base, exponent/2)*pow(base, exponent/2) :
           base * pow(base, (exponent-1)/2) * pow(base, (exponent-1)/2);
}
```

---

"I heard that it is up to the compiler whether the constexpr function is evaluated in compile time or not."

True, AFAIK. The compiler isn't required to do constant-initialization at compile-time, but if you use the result of a constexpr function as a non-type template argument, it has to compute the result at compile-time.

```
std::cout << std::integral_constant<int, pow(2, 4)>::value << std::endl;
```

Also see the approach using `integral_constant` as parameter of `pow` in [Andy Prowl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1932150/andy-prowl)'s answer.

Here's how you can enforce compile-time evaluation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// insert a constexpr `pow` implementation, e.g. the one from above

template < typename T, T base, unsigned exponent >
using pow_ = std::integral_constant < T, pow(base, exponent) >;

// macro == error prone, you have been warned
#define POW(BASE, EXPONENT) (pow_ < decltype(BASE), BASE, EXPONENT > :: value)

int main()
{
    std::cout << "pow(2, 4): " << pow_<int, 2, 4>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "pow(2, 4): " << POW(2, 4) << std::endl;
}
```

---

Please leave a comment if you downvote so I can improve my answer.

Comment: @BЈовић No it isn't but why do you need a template metaprogramming approach? You can use `constexpr` functions (and their results) in metaprogramming as well.

Comment: @BЈовић: Seriously, who cares? “Are you sure you used the blue hammer for this nail?”

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig Ok, the title confused me.

Comment: @BЈовић sorry for the confusion title. Maybe it should be changed to compile time power of int.

Comment: Please, explain the rationale after the *Yoda Condition* `(0 == N)`, I think that there's a good reason to do the `constant == value` trick but I cannot explain it.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster If you're referring to the order (constant first, then variable) that is to prevent errors like `if(N = 0)`. I'll update the code to make `N` const as well, it doesn't matter here.

Comment: @DyP yes, I was referring to that, but I betted that the reason was more impressive :P

Comment: It would be even better if it used [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. As a small `c++20` update you could mention that replacing `constexpr` with `consteval` to enforce compile-time evaluation.

Comment: @wychmaster Hmm, not sure if `consteval` _strictly_ requires evaluation at compile-time... I mean, a consteval function call _must_ be possible to evaluate at compile, but who is forcing the compiler to do so?

Comment: @dyp Now that you say that, I am not sure either. I thought that was the whole point of `consteval` and I guess every halfway decent compiler will evaluate at compile-time to perform further optimizations, but the description on [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval) does not say that the compiler has to perform a compile-time evaluation. So it seems you are right. Still asking myself, if there is any case, a compiler might choose to not evaluate at compile-time...

Comment: @wychmaster See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58467438/420683 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/64742167/420683

Answer (score 20):

When you find yourself in need of partially specializing a function template (beware, this does not mean that *in this case* you are in need, as [DyP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16443849/1932150) shows), you may either resort to overloading (see the last update at the end of this answer) or, if that's not possible, wrap that function template into a class template, and have a static, non-template member function replace your original function template (and its specializations):

```
namespace detail
{
    template<class T, int N>
    struct helper
    {
        static constexpr T pow(const T x){
            return helper<T, N-1>::pow(x) * x;
        }
    };

    template<class T>
    struct helper<T, 1> // Unnecessary specialization! (see the edit)
    {
        static constexpr T pow(const T x){
            return x;
        }
    };

    template<class T>
    struct helper<T, 0>
    {
        static constexpr T pow(const T x){
            return 1;
        }
    };
}
```

Then, you could provide a helper function template that delegates to the specialization of your helper class template:

```
template<int N, class T>
T constexpr pow(T const x)
{
    return detail::helper<T, N>::pow(x);
}
```

Here is a [*live example*](http://ideone.com/2K9UzJ).

**EDIT:**

Notice, that the specialization for `N == 1` is actually not necessary. I kept it in the original text because the purpose of this answer was mainly to show how to workaround the impossibility of partially specializing function templates *in general* - so I translated the original program piece-by-piece.

As noted by Dyp [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443682/c-power-of-integer-template-meta-programming/16443823#comment23585303_16443823), however, this would be enough:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<class T, int N>
    struct helper
    {
        static constexpr T pow(const T x){
            return helper<T, N-1>::pow(x) * x;
        }
    };

    template<class T>
    struct helper<T, 0>
    {
        static constexpr T pow(const T x){
            return 1;
        }
    };
}
```

**UPDATE:**

As a further remark, please keep in mind that even when you *can* specialize function templates (e.g. with explicit - not partial - specializations), it is generally not a good idea to do so, because function template specialization does not normally behave as one would expect.

Most of those situations that may seem to ask for function template specialization can actually be achieved through *overloading*, powered by well-known techniques such as **tag dispatching**. An example is proposed by Potatoswatter [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443682/c-power-of-integer-template-meta-programming#comment23585816_16443823), pointing out that `std::integral_constant` could be used in this situation:

```
template<class T>
inline constexpr T pow(const T x, std::integral_constant<int, 0>){
    return 1;
}

template<class T, int N>
inline constexpr T pow(const T x, std::integral_constant<int, N>){
    return pow(x, std::integral_constant<int, N-1>()) * x;
}

template<int N, class T>
inline constexpr T pow(const T x)
{
    return pow(x, std::integral_constant<int, N>());
}
```

However, all these guidelines on "how to solve problems that seem to require function template partial specialization" should be taken into consideration when they are really needed. In this concrete case, as DyP showed in his answer, they are not.

Comment: @taocp: Thanks a lot for your appreciation, but you are celebrating me more than I deserve ;) I wish I knew every bit of C++

Comment: Is the partial specialization for `N == 1` required?

Comment: @DyP: Good catch, actually no, it isn't. The purpose of my answer was mostly to show the OP how to translate a function template partial specialization into a class template partial specialization. But I will edit, thank you

Comment: Thank you. It helps me a lot. I was having hard time to pick the accepted answer. Because both were great.

Comment: I just picked the simplest solution. Sorry.

Comment: @Sungmin: That's all right, DyP's answer shows the right way to solve this particular problem, mine was mostly a guideline for more general situations

Comment: More general guideline is, if you feel you need function template partial specialization, use overloading instead. This can be done using a `std::integral_constant` argument instead of a helper class. Essentially a form of tag dispatching.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Indeed, overloading is in general preferable over function template specialization, but it does not always replace it - although in this case it does. I will edit the answer, anyway

Comment: @Sungmin: Thank you, although what Potatoswatter wrote is correct - and I tried to reflect that in the last update to my answer

Comment: @0x499602D2: Indeed, it does (7.1.5/2)

Comment: Is both `constexpr` and `inline` really needed?

Comment: @0x499602D2: No, it is not

Comment: @0x499602D2: I copy-pasted the example from the OP's text and shown the minimal fixes. Probably the same applies for the accepted answer. Also, it is possible that by the time I answered I did not know about this yet

Comment: `N` should be unsigned.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution with a single function:

```
template <int N, class T> 
constexpr T pow(const T& x) 
{
    return N > 1 ? x*pow<(N-1)*(N > 1)>(x) 
                 : N < 0 ? T(1)/pow<(-N)*(N < 0)>(x) 
                         : N == 1 ? x 
                                  : T(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

template<int N, int M>
struct Pow
{
    enum { res = N * Pow<N,M-1>::res};
};


template<int N>
struct Pow<N,0>
{
    enum {res = 1};
};
int main()
{
    cout<<Pow<2,3>::res<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: Cool solution, this is what I was looking for

Comment: `M` should be unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

Clean and simple solution here:

```
#include <cstddef>

template<size_t N, size_t P>
struct pow_constexpr { constexpr static auto value = N * pow_constexpr<N, P-1>::value; };

template<size_t N>
struct pow_constexpr<N, 1> { constexpr static auto value = N; };

template<size_t N>
struct pow_constexpr<N, 0> { constexpr static auto value = 1; };

int main() {
    return pow_constexpr<2, 30>::value; // 1073741824
}
```

Comment: `pow_constexpr<N, 1>` not needed. Others above can calculate for variables too. eg `constexpr int p5 = pow<5>(2);` and  `int x = 1;
    int p5 = pow<5>(x);`

Comment: thanks! for computing variables I'll choose constexpr funcs with loop, I'll run runtime and compile-time.