# Use integer template argument to create compiletime double

Tags: c++

Is it possible to create a double which holds the value of 1*10^x where x is based on a integer template parameter. So something like:

```
template < int exp >
struct DoubleValue
{
    static constexpr double value = ????;
}

double d = DoubleValue<20>::value; // = 1e20
double d = DoubleValue<-20>::value; // = 1e-20
```

As it can be created with litterals, it seems that something like this should be possible.

I would like the value to be evaluated at compile time (so std::pow will not work as far as I know). 
Also, if possible, I would like to be able to avoid actual iterative computations ((maybe unfounded) fear for precision problems). I would also like to be able to use larger values as exponent, like for example 200, which makes it impossible to store the value in a standerd integer type.

Comment: maybe `std::pow(10, exp)`?

Comment: @iBug he needs something with compile time, so `std::pow` will not work since it is not `constexpr`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ power of integer, template meta programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443682/c-power-of-integer-template-meta-programming)

Comment: *"I would like the value to be evaluated at compile time*" &mdash; What would be the use for this? To speed-up your runtime?

Comment: I added static constexpr, I was indeed sloppy :)

Comment: To give some background, I would like te create a way to parse input numbers like 100M, 100K, 0.1m where the characters represent metric prefixes (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix). But it should also work with our internal types (which I can create with an exponent). So I would like to create a template-specialization for creating a double with such exponent.

Comment: @RubixCube are [user-defined literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) what you are looking for? (C++11)

Comment: @RubixCube also: instead of evaluating the actual value, you could choose to store a different representation, namely base + exponent instead and have a way to get the actual value at run time. That gives you fully `constexpr` building blocks, deferring actual computations until runtime.

Comment: @user268396 It is used for parsing input and convert it to different types, PODs as well as a type similar as you describe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that your compiler supports C++14 or higher (which should be a valid assumption in the year 2019) this is very simple using a `constexpr` function:

```
constexpr double myPow(double x, int exp)
{
    double pow = 1.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < exp; ++i)
        pow *= x;
    for (int i = 0; i > exp; --i)
        pow /= x;
    return pow;
}

template < int exp >
struct DoubleValue
{
    static constexpr double value = myPow(10.0, exp);
};
```

See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/YMJLnE) to verify that it works and that even without optimization the value is generated at compile time.

Depending on your use case you might not even need the `DoubleValue` struct but can directly use `myPow()`.

---

### Update

As pointed out by @Bob__ in the comments, there may be better algorithms regarding numerical precision than the one presented here. But since C++14 [many basic language features](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#extended-constexpr) can be used in the body of a `constexpr` function. So, as long as you don't need any external library for it, you are free to implement whatever algorithm fits your needs.

Comment: Off topic: "_Assuming that your compiler supports C++14 or higher (which should be a valid assumption in the year 2019)_"; When writing new projects, sure. But, in the project, that I am working on, we still have pieces of code being compiled with VS2003.. Legacy projects FTW!

Comment: Luckily, the project I wanted to use this in was just updated :). I chose this anwer as it is clearer in its intent compared to recursive template solutions.

Comment: Please note that the algorithm used here is more prone to numeric errors than other alternatives: https://wandbox.org/permlink/tiupixvpbtwo9Zwd

Answer (score 1):

If you want it at compile time without `std::pow`, this should do it:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int e>
struct DoubleValue {
    static constexpr double value = 10.0 * DoubleValue<e - 1>::value;
};
template <>
struct DoubleValue<0> {
    static constexpr double value = 1.0;
};
int main() {
    std::cout << DoubleValue<20>::value << '\n'; //1e+20
}
```

[C++ Fiddle](http://cpp.sh/8m2nt)

Comment: What about the case of `std::cout << DoubleValue<-10>::value << std::endl;`?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius It is not hard to upgrade the code to work with negative powers, the idea stays the same.

Comment: @lisyarus Idea, yes, but one can't just throw `if`, or ternary expression, in there, since the both branches would need to be resolved, which would lead to infinite recursion. One would need to do more, than what is shown here, to force the same template to work with both positive, and negative numbers.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius You are absolutely right, this needs some template machinery to work, albeit pretty standard one, but potentially not familiar to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need the value to available in compile time, pretty much the only way to solve it, that came to my mind is recursive templates. However, the fact, that you need for said template to do different things, based on the signedness of the passed value, complicates things. First thing that would come to mind, would be to write such a recursive template:

```
template <int exp>
struct DoubleValue
    {
    static constexpr double value = (exp < 0
                                     ? DoubleValue<exp+1>::value / 10
                                     : 10 * DoubleValue<exp-1>::value);
    };

// Default case
template <>
struct DoubleValue<0>
    {
    static constexpr double value = 1;
    };
```

However, such solution wouldn't work, due to the fact, that both branches of the ternary expression, would need to be resolved, and that would, always, lead to the infinite recursion, since one of the branches wouldn't tend to 0. Then, SFINAE came to mind:

```
// Base case.
template <int exp, class Enable = void>
struct DoubleValue
    {
    };

// Case when exp is positive
template <int exp>
struct DoubleValue<exp, typename std::enable_if<(exp > 0)>::type>
    {
    static constexpr double value = 10 * DoubleValue<exp-1>::value;
    };

// Case when exp is negative
template <int exp>
struct DoubleValue<exp, typename std::enable_if<(exp < 0)>::type>
    {
    static constexpr double value = DoubleValue<exp+1>::value / 10;
    };

// Default case.
template <>
struct DoubleValue<0>
    {
    static constexpr double value = 1;
    };
```

[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tHMOgtOvGWWjjCL9).

Comment: This is definitely not the only was - see answer by @sebrockm.

Comment: @lisyarus Sure, what I meant was "the only way that came to my mind". Edited to clarify that.