# Not sure why method is not working for large numbers

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int print(int n, int t) {

    for (unsigned long long i = pow(10, n - 1); i < pow(10, n); i++) {
        if (i % t == 0)
            return i;
    }
    
    return -1;
}

int main() {

    int n, t;

    cin >> n >> t;

    cout << print(n ,t);
}
```

Hi, I have a method where it finds a whole number that is n digits long and divisible by t. It works correctly for almost all cases, except when `n` is large. One problematic example is when `n = 18` and `t = 8.`

I printed out `pow(10, n - 1)` with `set precision(18)` and the number is `10^17`. However, the answer I get back is `1569325056`, which is only `10` digits.

I don't understand how I get a number less than `10^18`, which should be the smallest number. Shouldn't an `unsigned long long int` be enough to hold the `10^18`?

Comment: But you're returning an `int`?

Comment: You should not be using `pow`, a floating point function, for integer-based problems.  Usage of such function makes the code broken.  Either have a table of integer-based powers of 10, or write an integer-based function that does the powers.  Also, you are repeatedly calling `pow` in the `for` part of the loop, which is inefficient.

Comment: using `pow` to get powers of integers is a bad idea: [Why does pow(5,2) become 24?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22264236/995714), [Why the result of pow(10,2) 99 instead of 100?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54057687/995714), [Why pow(10,5) = 9,999](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9704195/995714)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505675/power-of-an-integer-in-c

Comment: You can also add [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-does-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5-with-my-compiler-and-os) showing the vulnerability of using `pow`.

Comment: *"Shouldn't an `unsigned long long int` be enough to hold the `10^18`?"* -- this question is irrelevant since you are not printing an `unsigned long long int`.

Comment: (1) `pow()` is for `double`s, i.e. irrelevant for this case; don’t use it. (2) Don’t use an `int`. Its range is only –2³¹ to 2³¹ – 1. (3) `uint64_t` won’t solve the problem fully either; it only goes from `0` to 2⁶⁴ – 1. If you want *unlimited* integers, use [GNU MP](https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Class-Interface). (4) Your algorithm is as hugely inefficient as it gets. If you just want *any* n-digit number divisible by `t`, why not take the maximum n-digit number (n 9s), divide it by `t` and multiply it by `t`? If it’s still n-digit, you have your result. No reason to iterate.

Comment: I’ve added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70061957/8584929) showing both GNU MP and a reasonable algorithm for the number search. If the goal was to find the *smallest* n-digit number divisible by `t` (rather than *any* or the *biggest*), the algorithm can be trivially modified: Do the (integer) division and multiplication for n – 1 digits, then add the divisor once, check if you got exactly n digits → there you go.

Answer (score 1):

You return `i` which is `unsigned long long`, but your return type is `int`.

```
unsigned long long print(int n, int t) {

    for (unsigned long long i = pow(10, n - 1); i < pow(10, n); i++) {
        if (i % t == 0)
            return i;
    }
    return -1ULL;
}
```

But it is extremely inefficient this way, when `t` gets large and/or is a big prime, as the loop may have to loop about `t` times. Using the remainder, you can calculated much faster (be warned, this is a piece of untested C++ code, just to get the general idea out):

```
unsigned long long solve(int n, int t)
{
    //assuming n <= 18 and t is within `int` range
    unsigned long long smallest = pow(10, n-1), largest = pow(10, n);
    if (smallest % t == 0) {return smallest;}

    unsigned long long leftOver = smallest - smallest % t; leftOver += t;
    if (leftOver <= largest) {return leftOver;} else {return -1ULL;}
}
```

Comment: The use of `pow`, a floating point function, makes this answer broken.

Answer (score 0):

Use [GNU MP](https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Class-Interface) for unlimited integers. In the example below, you can use an *arbitrary* number of digits. Obtaining and checking of user inputs is (intentionally) left out for the sake of brevity.

```cpp
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  const size_t n_digits{22};
  const mpz_class divisor{77777777777777777777_mpz};

  const mpz_class digits{mpz_class{std::string(n_digits, '9')}
                         / divisor
                         * divisor};
  const std::string output{digits.get_str()};

  if (output.size() == n_digits) {
    std::cout << "An example " << n_digits
              << "-digit number divisible by " << divisor
              << " is " << output;
  } else {
    std::cout << "There is no " << n_digits
              << "-digit number divisible by " << divisor;
  }
  std::cout << ".\n";
}
```

Link with `-lgmp -lgmpxx`.

```
An example 22-digit number divisible by 77777777777777777777 is 9955555555555555555456.
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `print` function returns an `int`, so when you `return i;`, `i` get casted back into an `int`.

Change your code to:

```
unsigned long long print(int n, int t) {

    for (unsigned long long i = pow(10, n - 1); i < pow(10, n); i++) {
        if (i % t == 0)
            return i;
    }
    
    return -1ULL;
}
```

Comment: The usage of `pow`, a floating point function, makes this answer broken.