# Why the C++ program is showing wrong answer

Tags: c++

I have written a code. I am getting an wrong or unexpected answer form the code. The value of **2nd** index of the array named **arr** should be **800** but it is showing **799**. Other values are right.

Here is my C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n = 9876, count = 0, temp, size = (int) to_string(n).length();
  vector<int> arr;

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    temp = (n % 10) * pow(10, i);
    arr.push_back(temp);
    n /= 10;
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The output of the program is:
`6 70 799 9000`

Here the third number is `799` but I think it should be `800`

Why I'm getting this wrong answer?

Comment: Use `round()` to convert the floating point number to the nearest integer rather than rounding down.

Comment: You're dealing with floats, and that 799, is actually determined to be, before becoming an integer, 799.99999999... etc.

Comment: The function `pow` should be for experts only. I see so many misuses of it by beginners that the function should not be taught in courses! For integers, use a loop. For squaring `double` values, multiply the value by itself. The `pow` is for very special uses, I nearly never used it in 20 years of programming.

Comment: @SatyajitRoy -- Do not use floating point functions such as `pow` to solve integer-based problems.  Your program is instantly broken by using `pow`, and it doesn't matter if `pow` just happened to give you the right value.  There are implementations of `pow` where you will *not* always get the correct results, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678481/why-does-pown-2-return-24-when-n-5-with-my-compiler-and-os)

Comment: The other comments make it clear that you shouldn't use pow. However, there is a simple algorithm that you can use to compute the power of an integer efficiently and accurately. Other than the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17504209/10913049), you might also want to learn the [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) itself.

Comment: Before the `for` loop, insert this statement:  `int power = 1;` at the end of the loop, insert `power * = 10;`.  Your `temp` statement then becomes: `temp = (n % 10) * power;`

Comment: Another technique is to read the input as a string.  You can treat the string as an array to access the digits.